# Toggling a div on the click of an other div

Tags: javascript, css, html

I would love to know how to toggle a div when I click on an other div. For instance, I have couple of buttons, and one of them is called "about". Now, when I click on that button, I want a div to toggle on the bottom of the page. I also would like to know how to make it so that if the user clicks on a different button, say, "work", it toggles the about page off and the work page on. I believe it's possible to do this with jQuery, but I have absolutely zero experience with it. All help greatly appreciated!

**HTML**

```
<div id="mainmenu">
    <p id="welcome1">Welcome to my website.</p>
    <p id="welcome2">Please click on one of the smaller circles.</p>
    <div id="mainmenubg"></div>

    <div id="about">
        <p id="about1">ABOUT</p>
        <div class="bg"></div>
    </div>



    <div id="work">
        <p id="work1">WORK</p>
        <div class="bg"></div>
    </div>


    <div id="school">
        <p id="school1">SCHOOL</p>
        <div class="bg"></div>
    </div>


    <div id="contact">
        <p id="contact1">CONTACT</p>
        <div class="bg"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/*The biggest parts in this style sheet are the animation codes. They take up the most, because they are compatible with almost all (updated) browsers.*/ 

/*Let's give that sucker a background image first.*/
body 
{
background-image:url('bg.png');
}

#mainmenu{
  animation: mainmenu ease 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transform-origin: ;
  -webkit-animation: mainmenu ease 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: ;
  -moz-animation: mainmenu ease 2s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-transform-origin: ;
  -o-animation: mainmenu ease 2s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-transform-origin: ;
  -ms-animation: mainmenu ease 2s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-transform-origin: ;

  /*Normal properties start here*/
    border-radius: 50%/50%;
    border-style:solid; 
    border-width:106px;
    border-color: #636363;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    xbackground: white;

    z-index:9001;


    position:absolute;
    left:100px;
    top:100px;
}

@keyframes mainmenu{
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    transform:  rotate(-360deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes mainmenu{
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -moz-transform:  rotate(-360deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -moz-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes mainmenu {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(-360deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes mainmenu {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -o-transform:  rotate(-360deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -o-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes mainmenu {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -ms-transform:  rotate(-360deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -ms-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
}


#about{
  animation: about ease 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transform-origin: ;
  -webkit-animation: about ease 5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: ;
  -moz-animation: about ease 5s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-transform-origin: ;
  -o-animation: about ease 5s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-transform-origin: ;
  -ms-animation: about ease 5s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-transform-origin: ;

    border-radius: 50%/50%;
    border-style:solid; 
    border-width:10px;
    border-color: #636363;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    position:absolute;
    left:500px;
    top:-100px;
}

@keyframes about{
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
  49% {
    opacity:0;
    transform:  scaleY(1) ;
  }
  50% {
    opacity:1;
    transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  52% {
    transform:  scaleX(2) scaleY(2) ;
  }
  56% {
    transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes about{
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -moz-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
  49% {
    opacity:0;
    -moz-transform:  scaleY(1) ;
  }
  50% {
    opacity:1;
    -moz-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  52% {
    -moz-transform:  scaleX(2) scaleY(2) ;
  }
  56% {
    -moz-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -moz-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes about {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
  49% {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform:  scaleY(1) ;
  }
  50% {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  52% {
    -webkit-transform:  scaleX(2) scaleY(2) ;
  }
  56% {
    -webkit-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes about {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -o-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
  49% {
    opacity:0;
    -o-transform:  scaleY(1) ;
  }
  50% {
    opacity:1;
    -o-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  52% {
    -o-transform:  scaleX(2) scaleY(2) ;
  }
  56% {
    -o-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -o-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes about {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -ms-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
  49% {
    opacity:0;
    -ms-transform:  scaleY(1) ;
  }
  50% {
    opacity:1;
    -ms-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  52% {
    -ms-transform:  scaleX(2) scaleY(2) ;
  }
  56% {
    -ms-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -ms-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
}


#work{
  animation: work ease 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transform-origin: ;
  -webkit-animation: work ease 5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: ;
  -moz-animation: work ease 5s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-transform-origin: ;
  -o-animation: work ease 5s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-transform-origin: ;
  -ms-animation: work ease 5s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-transform-origin: ;

    border-radius: 50%/50%;
    border-style:solid; 
    border-width:10px;
    border-color: #636363;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    position:absolute;
    left:550px;
    top:50px;
}

@keyframes work{
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
  52% {
    opacity:0;
    transform:  scaleY(1) ;
  }
  53% {
    opacity:1;
    transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  55% {
    transform:  scaleX(2) scaleY(2) ;
  }
  59% {
    transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes work{
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -moz-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
  52% {
    opacity:0;
    -moz-transform:  scaleY(1) ;
  }
  53% {
    opacity:1;
    -moz-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  55% {
    -moz-transform:  scaleX(2) scaleY(2) ;
  }
  59% {
    -moz-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -moz-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes work {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
  52% {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform:  scaleY(1) ;
  }
  53% {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  55% {
    -webkit-transform:  scaleX(2) scaleY(2) ;
  }
  59% {
    -webkit-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes work {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -o-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
  52% {
    opacity:0;
    -o-transform:  scaleY(1) ;
  }
  53% {
    opacity:1;
    -o-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  55% {
    -o-transform:  scaleX(2) scaleY(2) ;
  }
  59% {
    -o-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -o-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes work {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -ms-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
  52% {
    opacity:0;
    -ms-transform:  scaleY(1) ;
  }
  53% {
    opacity:1;
    -ms-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  55% {
    -ms-transform:  scaleX(2) scaleY(2) ;
  }
  59% {
    -ms-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -ms-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
}


#school{
  animation: school ease 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transform-origin: ;
  -webkit-animation: school ease 5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: ;
  -moz-animation: school ease 5s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-transform-origin: ;
  -o-animation: school ease 5s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-transform-origin: ;
  -ms-animation: school ease 5s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-transform-origin: ;

    border-radius: 50%/50%;
    border-style:solid; 
    border-width:10px;
    border-color: #636363;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    position:absolute;
    left:550px;
    top:210px;
}

@keyframes school{
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
  55% {
    opacity:0;
    transform:  scaleY(1) ;
  }
  56% {
    opacity:1;
    transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  58% {
    transform:  scaleX(2) scaleY(2) ;
  }
  62% {
    transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes school{
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -moz-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
  55% {
    opacity:0;
    -moz-transform:  scaleY(1) ;
  }
  56% {
    opacity:1;
    -moz-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  58% {
    -moz-transform:  scaleX(2) scaleY(2) ;
  }
  62% {
    -moz-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -moz-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes school {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
  55% {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform:  scaleY(1) ;
  }
  56% {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  58% {
    -webkit-transform:  scaleX(2) scaleY(2) ;
  }
  62% {
    -webkit-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes school {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -o-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
  55% {
    opacity:0;
    -o-transform:  scaleY(1) ;
  }
  56% {
    opacity:1;
    -o-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  58% {
    -o-transform:  scaleX(2) scaleY(2) ;
  }
  62% {
    -o-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -o-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes school {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -ms-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
  55% {
    opacity:0;
    -ms-transform:  scaleY(1) ;
  }
  56% {
    opacity:1;
    -ms-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  58% {
    -ms-transform:  scaleX(2) scaleY(2) ;
  }
  62% {
    -ms-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -ms-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
}


#contact{
  animation: contact ease 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transform-origin: ;
  -webkit-animation: contact ease 5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: ;
  -moz-animation: contact ease 5s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-transform-origin: ;
  -o-animation: contact ease 5s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-transform-origin: ;
  -ms-animation: contact ease 5s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-transform-origin: ;

    border-radius: 50%/50%;
    border-style:solid; 
    border-width:10px;
    border-color: #636363;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    position:absolute;
    left:500px;
    top:360px;    

}

@keyframes contact{
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
  58% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  59% {
    opacity:1;
    transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  61% {
    transform:  scaleX(2) scaleY(2) ;
  }
  65% {
    transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes contact{
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -moz-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
  58% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  59% {
    opacity:1;
    -moz-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  61% {
    -moz-transform:  scaleX(2) scaleY(2) ;
  }
  65% {
    -moz-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -moz-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes contact {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
  58% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  59% {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  61% {
    -webkit-transform:  scaleX(2) scaleY(2) ;
  }
  65% {
    -webkit-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes contact {
  0% {

    opacity:0;
    -o-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
  58% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  59% {
    opacity:1;
    -o-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  61% {
    -o-transform:  scaleX(2) scaleY(2) ;
  }
  65% {
    -o-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -o-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes contact {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    -ms-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
  58% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  59% {
    opacity:1;
    -ms-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  61% {
    -ms-transform:  scaleX(2) scaleY(2) ;
  }
  65% {
    -ms-transform:  scaleX(1) scaleY(1) ;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    -ms-transform:  rotate(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg) ;
  }
}




/*These are the large coloured circles around the buttons.*/
#mainmenubg{
    border-radius: 50%/50%;
    border-style:solid; 
    border-width:100px;
    border-color: #91A6BC;
    width: 406px;
    height: 406px;

    position:absolute;
    left:-103px;
    top:-103px;
}

/*Pay heed! This one here is a CLASS, not an ID!*/
.bg{
    border-radius: 50%/50%;
    border-style:solid; 
    border-width:5px;
    border-color: #91A6BC;
    width: 104px;
    height: 104px;

    position:absolute;
    left:-7px;
    top:-7px;
}




/*Below here are all the paragraphs and similiar things. They are all IDs.*/
#welcome1{
    font-size:35px;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-UltraLight;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    color:#404040;

    width:300px;

    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:50px;
    text-align:center;
}


#welcome2{
    font-size:25px;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Thin;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    color:#7A7A7A;

    width:300px;

    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
    left:50px;
    text-align:center;
}


#about1{
    font-size:25px;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Thin;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color:#404040;

    text-align:center;

    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:6px;
}


#work1{
    font-size:25px;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Thin;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color:#404040;

    text-align:center;

    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
}


#school1{
    font-size:22px;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Thin;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color:#404040;

    text-align:center;

    position:absolute;
    top:15px;
    left:3px;
}


#contact1{
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Thin;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color:#404040;

    text-align:center;

    position:absolute;
    top:19px;
    left:3px;
}
```

Link for my small project: http://speedy.sh/V6fqw/project.zip

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rsvyx/1) (Thanks to Kimmax)

EDIT: So, as you can see on the right side, there are four buttons. What I want is that if a user were to click on one of them, a div on the bottom of the page gently fades in, the speed of which similar to the speed of the large circle.

Comment: please share your html sample so that we can help you

Comment: Alright, I'll add a link to a zip of my entire project.

Comment: Just create a sample on jsfiddle.net

Comment: @TobyvanKempen Show specific code for your divs and buttons here. we don't want to see the entire project

Comment: If I am not wrong you are talking about accordion. Try this http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: @Professor, I want the page at the bottom to gently fade in. Also, my buttons are, well, somewhat different than those. But in a way, it's kinda like what your link holds.

Comment: can you post a fiddle instead of posting the link for your project?

Comment: I tried, but when I paste the link to my fiddle, it says "links to jsfiddle.net have to be accompanied by code". How can I still post the link?

Comment: I created one for you guys. http://jsfiddle.net/Rsvyx/1/

Comment: @TobyvanKempen Just add some code to your question and then you can post the link to your fiddle. You don't need to add all of your code, just add what's most relevant.

Comment: @Natalie, I'll remember that for further questions, but I will use Kimmax's link for now. Thanks though!

Comment: It's not that hard to do. I would create a container for your content at the bottom. In that container create four divs for your spefic content and add a class to all of them with `display: none` then add an unique id to all of them. Add a class to your circles and add`data-id` with the according id to your circles. Then add a click listener to your circle class, call `.fadeOut()` on all content divs, use the `$(this).data("id")` to get the id of the content div you wan't to show and call `.fadeIn()` on it. That should work.. I may add an exampsle as soon as I'm home.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Kimmax. I am very grateful, and I will let you know if it works as soon as possible.

Comment: @Kimmax, I would very much like it if you could make an example. I have no idea what click listeners are, or what '$(this).data("id")' means.

Comment: Okay I made an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Rsvyx/3/
Maybe a mod can review `the On Hold` status, so I can write a complete answer with explaination.

Comment: Alright, I'll implement this right now. I think I can manage to reverse-engineer your code so that I can implement it - it's how I learned HTML.  I'll let you know if I come across any glitches. I wish I could verify your comment!

Comment: Heh, I think I've hit a bump. Could you please take a look at this link? http://jsfiddle.net/Whitevan_Candyman/2xrD3/1/

Comment: This time there is nothing wrong with your code, but you forgot to enable jQuery in jsFiddle. You can enable it in the left sidebar by changing the `No-Library (Pure JS)` to `jQuery 2.x (edge)` or any other version you whish to use. One more hint: You can leave the `<html>` and `<head>` section out, as well as the `<body>` tag. Your Javascript and style will be applied automatically.

Comment: That's strange, though. It won't work in my browser when not viewing through jsfiddle. Oh, hey! They removed the "on hold" status!

Comment: It won't show the circle I made to contain the content. It does contain the content in jsfiddle, but not the container. Also, it won't work in my browser. Does the javascript have to be in a separate file?

PS. They removed the "on hold" status!

Comment: I also noticed that your example works in jsfiddle but not when I put them in files and launch it from my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Idea

Create a container for the content. This container should be filled with divs for your content and every single div in the container should get the content class. Also every single div in the container needs and unique ID. Add a class to every circle that should trigger a content change, but use the same class for every circle (For example `trigger` or `circle`). The next step is to specific the content which should be loaded in a `data-xx` attribute and use the ID you specified in the content divs before as identifier, as an example `data-id` or `data-content`.
Now it comes to Javascript. Register an [`click event`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) with the class you added to your triggers. When the event now fires, fade the current content out by calling [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) on the content class. After that get the *sender* via jQuerys `this` and receive the content-id by using the [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function. Now we can call [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) on the element that raised the `click event` and we are done.

### **Implementation**

**Adjust the triggers**

```
<div id="about" class="trigger" data-content="contentAbout">
</div>
```

First I added the class `trigger` so we can handle `click` events for it.
Secondly I added the `data-content` attribute, so we know what content should be shown later.

**Adjust the content box**

```
<div id="contentAbout" class="content">
</div>
```

Fist I set the `id` of the div to something that says whats in it. `content` + whats in it `About`.
Secondly the div needs to know that its a content div so add the class `content`.

**The content holder**

All the content divs have to be holed together, so we need to wrap with another div.

```
<div id="contentHolder">
    <!-- Content boxes go in here -->
</div>
```

**CSS magic**

We need to hide the content until it should be shown, so define a rule in the css-sheet for that.

```
.content {
    display: none;
}
```

This will hide the content boxes until we fade them in later.
Also we need adjust the position of the content-holder so it will be shown at the bottom.
Example:

```
#contentHolder {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -500px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Time for the real magic**

After finishing all the preparatory work, we can create our Javascript to get life in our little thing.

```
$(function() {
    $(".circle").click(function(){
        $(".content").fadeOut();
        $("#" + $(this).data("id")).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

```
$(function() {
}
```

will be executed as soon as the page finished loading.

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
});
```

registers an `click event` on all elements with the class `trigger`. Everything in the function will be executed when the user clicks on one of the element.

```
$(".content").fadeOut();
```

fades out every element with the id `content`. And

```
$("#" + $(this).data("content")).fadeIn();
```

fades in the element that matches the id specified in the `data-content` attribute.

Please note that you of curse have to include jQuery in the `<head>` section of your document. Example include:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

### Done

Comment: WOW! I added an incorrect library! It's working in my browser now too! I have one minor glitch, however. When the page loads, the page background is visible. Do you know how to make the page background disappear and appear on the clicks of the buttons?

Comment: Can you tell me which page background you mean? The one behind the content?

Comment: With page background I meant the #contentHolder. It doesn't fade in/fade out, but the content does. Also, it's visible when the page loads.

Comment: Not a problem at all. I would suggest hiding it until the first content is shown?

Comment: ...hehe, how exactly do I do that? Adding `display:none;` to `#contentHolder` doesn't seem to do the trick. It just hides the entire `#contentHolder` and its contents.

Comment: Add `display: none` to your `#contentHolder` section in the css and add `if(!$("#contentHolder").hasClass("shown")){ $("#contentHolder").fadeIn(); $("#contentHolder").addClass("shown"); }` before the `$("#" + $(this).data("id")).fadeIn();` in your javascript.

Comment: No problem! I'm here to help :)